# Finding the range with a statistics calculator

Tags: math-software, calculator

Is there a button on statistics calculators that easily finds the range of the numbers? I am using window's pre-installed calculator.

[image: Window's calculator]

Comment: What kind of calculator do you mean?

Comment: Its a 2 line code in MATLAB and slightly more in C/C++/Python. When you say calculator, do you mean hardware or software?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm I don't know of any hardware calculator which do so, since it is so trivial to calculate the range.

Basically the range is the maximum number minus the minimum number. In your example it is just $40.5-34.3=6.2$.

If you have many numbers, you can use spreadsheet if you like. In Excel it is just =MAX([cells]) - MIN([cells]).

Comment: Thanks. It's just kind of tedious to find the minimum and maximum numbers when you have lots of entries.